# minicom has me typing every character twice! What is wrong?

Tags: terminal, serial-port

minicom has me typing every character twice, which is extremely tiring. That is I have to press 'aa' to get 'a' and so on.

Does anyone know which setting is wrong, or what I should do?

I have Beaglebone Black with a custom Linux kernel 3.12.24 on a minimal rootfile-system, connected with the UBS-serial adapter, and hooked up to Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Describe your setup.  What is on the other end of the serial link?

Comment: I will have to get back to you tomorrow. But I will. Thx!

Comment: I have a BeagleBoneBlack with a http://www.adafruit.com/products/954 USB-to-serial adapter. Then I enter "minicom" and it works, but I have to double-tap each key...

Comment: Your description is still vague.  Edit your original question with the hardware and software used at both ends of the serial link.  When you type a key in a *terminal emulator* program, the displayed (or not displayed) character is generated either locally (not commom) ***or*** (remotely) by the program on the other end of the serial link (most common configuration).  So the issue could be either the transmission and/or the reception at either the near or far end of the serial link or both ends.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem once trying to communicate with a USB modem.

In my case the problem was that the modem had the echo function activated and I activated the echo in minicom too.
I solved it by deactivating the echo in minicom (Ctrl+A E)